# Plotting data with binned_statistic_2d and sum showing unwanted values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, imshow

I'm plotting the energy distribution of lightning in the Med sea, and I'm plotting my data with imshow and binned_statistic_2d.

I successfully plotted the mean of the lightning energy, but for a reason, I can't understand the imshow plot is looking weird in the sum plot(colors unwanted areas with purple, see left plot in the image).

This is the code I'm using-

```
 plot_3vars_sum = binned_statistic_2d(longs, lats, energies, statistic= 'sum', bins=[467, 175])
plot_3vars_mean = binned_statistic_2d(longs, lats, energies, statistic=np.mean, bins=[467, 175])
ax0.plot(long_points_med, lat_points_med)
ax1.plot(long_points_med, lat_points_med)
imshow_sum = ax0.imshow(plot_3vars_sum.statistic.T, origin='lower', extent=[min(longs), max(longs), min(lats), max(lats)])
imshow_mean = ax1.imshow(plot_3vars_mean.statistic.T, origin='lower', extent=[min(longs), max(longs), min(lats), max(lats)])
ax0.set_ylim(ymin=28, ymax= 47)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=28, ymax= 47)
ax0.set_xlim(xmin=-7, xmax=37)
ax1.set_xlim(xmin=-7, xmax=37)
imshow_sum.set_clim(1, 100000)
imshow_mean.set_clim(1, 10000)
cb0 = fig.colorbar(imshow_sum, ax=ax0, shrink=0.6)
cb1 = fig.colorbar(imshow_mean, ax=ax1, shrink=0.6)
plt.title(f'This is {month} in 2009-10')
plt.show()
```

longs, lats, and energies are simply lists of floats.

The image I'm getting is-
[image]

I tried ignoring nans and setting the color bar limits to above 1, but nothing works...
Can I get some help, please? I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe the `mean` array  but not the `sum` array contains NaN values that appear transparent.

Comment: Yeah you're right about the nans... I saw that mean has nan values, but all other options in statistic shows 0s. I'll close the question and open another one I guess on how to make 0 into nan. thanks!

Comment: Just modify your cmap with [`.set_under(alpha=0)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html) while setting `vmin` to a value above zero.

Comment: Bless you and all your children sir, that worked

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that when using mean, some of the bins contain "NaN" values while the result of "Sum" contains 0s.
I'll try and find a way to make 0 into nan in the sum.
question closed I guess? :-)